# 500 internal server erro when doing jquery ajax post in zen cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zen-cart

hi i am using zen cart and have this code, I keep getting 500 internal server error and im not sure if it is the code or something in my php script here are both:

```
<?php
global $db

$partNum = trim(strtolower($_POST['partNum']));
$partNum = mysql_escape_string($partNum);

$query = "SELECT products_model FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " WHERE products_model = '$partNum' LIMIT 1";
$result = $db->Execute($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num;
mysql_close();
```

and jquery

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/includes/templates/theme376/phpScripts/check.php",
   data: 'partNum='+ partNum,
   cache: false,
   success: function(response){
if(response == 1){
$('#partNum').css('border', '3px #C33 solid');  
$('#tick').hide();
$('#cross').fadeIn();
}else{
$('#partNum').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
$('#cross').hide();
$('#tick').fadeIn();
     }

}
});
```

here is the error

```
POST http://mysite.com/includes/templates/theme376/phpScripts/check.php?partNum=wwww 500 (Internal Server Error) /min/?f=/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_fileuploader.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery-1.7.1.min.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js&1332216833:38
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send /min/?f=/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_fileuploader.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery-1.7.1.min.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js&1332216833:38
f.extend.ajax /min/?f=/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_fileuploader.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery-1.7.1.min.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js&1332216833:38
partNum_check index.php:307
f.event.dispatch /min/?f=/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_fileuploader.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery-1.7.1.min.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js,/includes/templates/theme376/jscript/jscript_jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js&1332216833:37
f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

Comment: 500 error means server-side, so the error will most likely be in the PHP.

Comment: found it, it was an error with the was i was connecting to the db

Answer (score 0):

Take partnum out of data and use it as a query string.

You're just getting a generic 500 error? no details?

What happens if you put ?partnum=blah in the request URL?

I'm not sure you want query parameters in "data" like that. That's meant for data, not query strings.

Comment: just tried ?partnum=blah still getting the 500 error look at updated post